# How to check if NumLock is enabled

Tags: powershell

Recently I ran into an issue with a laptop that had NumLock disabled automatically at certain times (such as when coming out of sleep mode). This prompted me to look for ways to programmatically check if NumLock was off, and if so, turn it on.

I'm looking for the best way to accomplish this. I want to run the script when certain events occur, such as when logging on to the laptop. I plan to do this with a scheduled task, and I'd prefer to use PowerShell over VBScript, but I'd be happy to use whatever works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PowerShell, `[console]::NumberLock` is a Read Only property that will evaluate to true if NumLock is enabled.

The script I ended up writing is as follows:

```
if(-not [console]::NumberLock){ 
    $w = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell; 
    $w.SendKeys('{NUMLOCK}'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Thriggle's answer above, you can ensure NumLock never gets turned off by adding a loop. Note that this is pretty hard on CPU:

```
While($true){
if(-not [console]::NumberLock){ 
    $w = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell; 
    $w.SendKeys('{NUMLOCK}'); 
}
}
```