# How to use .VBS code to detect if NumLock key is on / off and then turn it on?

Tags: windows

Is it possible to use code in .VBS to detect if the NumLock key is on / off, and then add code to it that turns the NumLock key on if it detects that it is off?

Code example for detecting whether NumLock is on or off:

If GetNumlockState() = True Then
Wscript.Echo "Numlock is ON"
Else
Wscript.Echo "Numlock is FF"
End If

Function GetNumlockState()
strResult = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("powershell.exe -command [console]::NumberLock").StdOut.ReadLine
If strResult = "True" Then GetNumlockState = True Else GetNumlockState = False
End Function

Code example for turning on the NumLock key:

set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}"

How can I make it:

1. Connect the code to detect whether the NumLock key is on or off in such a way that the second code, i.e. the one for turning the NumLock key on, starts working only when it detects that NumLock is off ???
2. Not to display any notifications and information windows, that is, to do it silently in the background.

Thank you very much in advance for your answers.

Comment: Please google "wscript check numlock" for obvious solutions first, repeating them here is not useful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41234687/62576 has an answer that will do exactly what you're asking. Found through the google search suggested by @HansPassant

Comment: I'm looking for something specifically written in .VBS .... the link I got from you is, unfortunately, PowerShell ;/

Answer (score 2):

I handled this way and it works fine now:

```vb
If GetNumLockState() = True Then
    ' NumLock Already ON. Bypass (Or do something...)
Else 
    ' NumLock is Off
    set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
    WshShell.SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}" 
End If 

Function GetNumLockState() 
    strResult = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("powershell.exe -command [console]::NumberLock").StdOut.ReadLine
    If strResult = "True" Then 
        GetNumLockState = True
    Else 
        GetNumLockState = False 
    End If
End Function
```

I just don't know how to disable the appearance of the .cmd console which you can see for about one second on the desktop when pressing the NumLock key.

Can I ask for an answer, what do I have to enter so that the .cmd console is not displayed/is not visible while the script is running?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaoOr.png)

Comment: In order to run the .VBS code that turns on the Numlock key in such a way that it is with an invisible window, add the .VBS code to the autostart with the content CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "cscript %windir%\Location.vbs", 0, False and in place of %windir%\Location.vbs set your path and the appropriate name to the main .VBS file so that numlock is enabled invisibly. So it works so that one .VBS file only invisibly fires another .VBS code to get the numlock key on.